# Qt QML font awesome not working on MAC and IOS

Tags: qt, qml

I am working on QML and loading the font awesome using FontLoader

```
FontLoader {
    id: awesomeLoader
    name: "awesome"
    source: "qrc:/images/fontawesome-webfont.ttf"
}
```

Everything just find on Linux and Android, but it is not working on IOS and MAC, the font icon become empty rectangle.

This is how I use it :

```
Text {
    font.pointSize: 20
    font.family: "awesome"
    anchors.fill: parent
    text: isBackButton ? "\uf053" : "\uf0c9"
    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
}
```

Is there anything special on MAC / IOS?

Comment: You should show us your usage of the font (with e.g. `Text`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're setting `font.family`:

```
font.family: awesomeLoader.name
```

One thing I noticed on Windows was that I could get icons to show up without setting `font.family: "FontAwesome"` (I forgot to do it), but when switching to macOS they would be broken.

Comment: You are right, on Mac and IOS i need to set font.family to "FontAwesome" and everything is working now.

Answer (score 0):

It works in this way:

```
FontLoader {
    id: awesomeLoader
    //name: "awesome" (Comment or delete)
    source: "qrc:/images/fontawesome-webfont.ttf"
}
```

In Text Item change font.family value to awesomeLoader.name (FontLoader id name)

```
Text {
    font.pointSize: 20
    font.family: awesomeLoader.name
    anchors.fill: parent
    text: isBackButton ? "\uf053" : "\uf0c9"
    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
}
```